I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application where I'm unable to save a list of items to a cart object
I am trying to make my first spring boot application, and i want to add a list of items to a cart. But for some reason the item list does not save to the database.
i have added a screenshot of the results the endpoints produce.
So far my code:
Account class:
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Account {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(length = 1000, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    {
        createdOn = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateOn;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Cart cart;

    // Constructor for Seeder
    public Account(String name, String email, String password) {
        this.cart = new Cart();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.createdOn = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}

Cart class:
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Cart {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne
    private Account account;

    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    {
        createdOn = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateOn;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
    private List<Item> items;

    private String test;
}


Item class:
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Item {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    {
        createdOn = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateOn;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private Cart cart;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id")
    private Game game;
    private Integer quantity;

    public Item(Game game, Integer quantity) {
        this.game = game;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}


Cart controller:
@RequestMapping("/carts")
@RestController
public class CartController {
    @Autowired
    CartService cartService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Cart> getAllCarts() {
        return cartService.getCarts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Cart getCartById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return cartService.getCartById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/add/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cart> addItemsToCart(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody List<Item> items) {
            if (cartService.updateCartContents(id, items)) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
            }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cart> deleteCart(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if (cartService.deleteCart(id)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("clearcart/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cart> clearCart(@PathVariable Long id){
        if (cartService.clearCart(id)){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("removeitem/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cart> removeCartItems(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Item item){
        if (cartService.removeCartItem(id,item)){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }

    // check out. dus zet cart om in purchase en clear de cart
    @PutMapping("checkout/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cart> checkout(@PathVariable Long id){
        try{
            cartService.checkout(id);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }
}

and the cart service:
@Service
public class CartService {
    @Autowired
    CartRepository cartRepository;
    @Autowired
    ItemRepository itemRepository;
    @Autowired
    PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

    public List<Cart> getCarts(){
        return cartRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Cart getCartById(Long id){
        return cartRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    }

    public boolean updateCartContents(Long id, List<Item> items){
        Optional<Cart> optionalCart = cartRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalCart.isPresent()) {
            Cart cart = optionalCart.get();
            cart.getItems().addAll(items);
            System.out.println("cart items before saving: " + cart.getItems());
            cartRepository.save(cart);
            System.out.println("cart items after saving: " + cart.getItems());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean deleteCart(Long id){
        if(cartRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            cartRepository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean clearCart(Long id){
        if(cartRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            Cart cart = cartRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
            cart.getItems().clear();
            cartRepository.save(cart);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean removeCartItem(Long id, Item itemToRemove){
        if(cartRepository.findById(id).isPresent()){
            Cart cart = cartRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
            cart.getItems().remove(itemRepository.findById(itemToRemove.getId()).orElseThrow());
            cartRepository.save(cart);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void checkout(Long id) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        Cart cart = cartRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
        //Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
        //purchase.setPurchasedItems(cart.getItems());
        //purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
        clearCart(id);
    }
}


I added a string variable named test to see if the cart doesn't get updated at all, but when i adjust that it does show in the cart. So the problem seems to be specifically with the List of Items. I added an console log to call the list, and in my console it does log it as if the items are added.
The output of the console logs are as follows:
`cart items before saving: [Item{id=1, createdOn=2024-05-05T12:49:57.343516400, lastUpdateOn=null, cart=null, game=null, quantity=null}, Item{id=2, createdOn=2024-05-05T12:49:57.344485400, lastUpdateOn=null, cart=null, game=null, quantity=null}, Item{id=3, createdOn=2024-05-05T12:49:57.344485400, lastUpdateOn=null, cart=null, game=null, quantity=null}]
cart items after saving: [Item{id=1, createdOn=2024-05-05T12:49:53.806481, lastUpdateOn=null, cart=null, game=com.united.Gamestore.Game.Game@2f5cee8, quantity=1}, Item{id=2, createdOn=2024-05-05T12:49:53.809481, lastUpdateOn=null, cart=null, game=com.united.Gamestore.Game.Game@7cedf75c, quantity=1}, Item{id=3, createdOn=2024-05-05T12:49:53.811481, lastUpdateOn=null, cart=null, game=com.united.Gamestore.Game.Game@6f5d6a00, quantity=1}]`

Your many-to-one/one-to-many relationship is bidirectional. When you are adding a new entry to the list you must set the reference in the target entity as well. Implement a helper method in the Cart entity like this:
public void addItem(Item item) {
    items.add(item);
    item.setCart(this);
}

Similar to this you should implement a method for removing the entry:
public void removeItem(Item item) {
    items.remove(item);
    item.setCart(null);
}

This way you will have the implementation in one place and the relationship will be synchronized correctly.
Based on: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
